# How to Passing array parameters to stored procedure in?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have these tables :
[image]
I have an array like `cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4` that want passed to sql server stored procedure.
 then check that them exist in PaperKeywors's table or not .
If yes, insert `PKeyID` of theme and `PID` (for example PID=1) to `PaperTag` and if no return them.
I know i must using TVP , and wrote these code in sql :

```
CREATE TYPE PaperKeywordsType AS TABLE
        ( PKeyword nvarchar(200) ,PKeyID int  )
```

And :

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPaperTag]
  (@dt AS PaperKeywordsType READONLY ,  @PID int)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.PaperTags(PID,PKeyID) 
  SELECT @PID,PaperKeywords.PKeyID FROM @dt tvp 
  inner join PaperKeywords on PaperKeywords.PKeyword = tvp.PKeyword
END
```

But it's not work for me. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C# you need to create a DataTable with the values and pass that to the stored procedure.  See this [SO Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5595484/1339616) You can also pass the values as a delimited string to the stored procedure and use a function in TSQL to convert the values to a table.  See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx) for a few examples.